# Laravel cannot get relationship data of a selected profile

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I just created a profile for users, and wish to show the education details related to the logged-in user or another selected user.

for this, I created an education model for users and gave a proper relationship to it both the sides. im not able to get any data from the education table of loged in user or another user. i used foreach tag in blade file. please revview my code. thanks.

**Education Model**

```
class Education extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $primaryKey = 'education_id';

    public function myusers()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User','user_id','education_id');
    }

}
```

**User Model**

```
  public function myeducation()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Education','education_id','user_id');
    }
```

**Profile Controller**

```
   public function index()
    {

         $user = Auth::user();


          return view('candidate.profile',['user'=>$user,]);
    }
```

**Blade file**

```
 @foreach ($user->myeducation as $education)
                    <div>
                       {{  $education->school }}
                    </div>

                @endforeach
```

**Table Structure of Education and Users**

```
**Education Table**

{
        Schema::create('education', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('education_id');
            $table->bigInteger('user_id');
            $table->string('school');
            $table->string('degree');
            $table->string('fieldOfStudy');
            $table->date('startDate');
            $table->date('endDate');
            $table->string('grade');
            $table->string('activities');
            $table->string('description');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
```

**user table.**

```
        $table->increments('user_id');
        $table->bigInteger('role_id');
        $table->bigInteger('membership_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('firstname');
        $table->string('lastname');
```

**there is no error message, but just blank**

```
Table entries

 DB::table('education')
            'user_id' => '2',
            'school' => 'University of Bedfordshire',
            'degree' => 'MBA',
            
        ]);



 DB::table('users')->insert([
            'user_id' => '1',
            'role_id' => '1',
            'firstname' => 'Mohammed',
            'lastname' => 'Sabeel',
            .......
        ]);

        DB::table('users')
            ' user_id' => '2'
            'role_id' => '2',
            'firstname' => 'zahida',
            'lastname' => 'sabeel',
            .......
        ]);
```

Comment: What do your tables look like? The keys seem a bit strange for relationships. You have `user_id` and `education_id` which sound like two different values. Keys should represent the **same** value in both tables (e.g. model variables `$user->id` === `$education->user_id`).  If that statement is already true, then you don't need to manually define the keys as Laravel will do it for you.

Comment: hello @matticustard. user>user_id and Education>user_id have same values. and the keys are already entered manually. please check the table structure attached on my question. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is in your relationship second and third argument. you are passing keys in wrong way.

in `Education` model use code like

```
public function myUser()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'user_id');
}
```

you need not to pass the third argument if you use the primary key for relationship. though you can pass the third argument to define which column to use to join the tables

```
public function myUser()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'user_id', 'user_id');
    // second argument user_id is from your education model while the third argument that is user_id is the primary key of your user model
    // i have used singular name for the relationship name with camel case
}
```

now in `User` model

```
public function myEducations()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Education', 'user_id');
    // user_id is the user_id of education model
    // and this is a has many relation i used plural form
}
```

read more about relationship in [laravel doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: thank you very much. this helped me. and now i can see the results.

Answer (score 0):

Before we begin, make sure that you have Education associated with that logged in User.

Try eager loading you relationship. Sometime this worked for me.
In your profile controller,

```
public function index()
{

     $user = Auth::user()->load('myeducation');


      return view('candidate.profile',['user'=>$user,]);
}
```

Even if it didn't work, Please share your table structure and table entries. So that we can examine clearly.

Comment: it doesn't work. please chech table structure